# Polymer: Trouble styling the <core-submenu>

Tags: html, css, polymer, web-component

I've created a simple menu inside a `<core-drawer-panel>` element using `<paper-item>` with the following:

```
<paper-item noink>
    <div class="core-menu-item">
        <core-icon icon="maps:beenhere"></core-icon>
        My Places 
    </div>
</paper-item>
```

As you can see, I've wrapped the insides with a `<div>` to adjust the icon and text style + positioning. 
Achieving this effect:
[image: Screenshot of paper items in drawer panel]

So my question is, **how can I style a `<core-submenu>` in a similar way to achieve the same results?**

I've tried following the [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-submenu) but styling seems to be very limited in the light DOM; I can only seem to add padding around the whole item, not specifically the icon (for which I'd like to add more padding).

Any suggestions?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `core-submenu` page describes part of the solution. Each core-submenu includes a `core-item` in its shadow DOM, which is used to display the title and icon for the submenu. You can style this using:

```
core-submenu::shadow #submenuItem {
  color: red;
}
```

The item itself contains a `core-icon` in its shadow root, with an ID of icon, so you can access that using:

```
core-submenu::shadow #submenuItem::shadow #icon {
  color: blue;
}
```